# How to use UTF8Encoding in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, utf-8, managed-c++

I need to change the below c# code to c++ code.

```
    public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }
```

on [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28VS.80%29.aspx) i found the c++ code for UTF8Encoding from which i created this code

```
    void StrToByteArray(string unicodeString)
    {
        UTF8Encoding^ utf8 = gcnew UTF8Encoding;
        array<Byte>^encodedBytes = utf8->GetBytes( unicodeString );
    }
```

but this gives me the following error

> Error 2   error C2664: 'cli::array
>   ^System::Text::Encoding::GetBytes(cli::array
>   ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::string' to
>   'cli::array

Why would it do this while it is identical to the documentation? (except i am using a normal string, but using a top level string^ gives me an error on that.)

i'm not sure if it is related but my code is managed.

note: i tried not worrying yet about returning any data till i get this working.

Comment: Maybe it wants unicodeString.c_str()?

Comment: Is your input definitely a C++ string not a managed string? If it's a C++ string then I'm not sure it makes sense to convert it to a managed string just to do a UTF-8 encoding - there's Windows APIs you can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string` is a different data type in C++ as it is in C#. Try using `System::String^` instead.